# MedianBlur issues with OpenCV

Tags: opencv, windows-phone-8, winrt-xaml

I'm using OpenCV for Windows Phone 8.1 (Windows runtime) in c++ with the release from MS Open Tech https://github.com/MSOpenTech/opencv.

This version is based on OpenCV 3 and the medianBlur function seemms to have a problem.
When I use a square image, the medianBlur works perfectly, but when I use a rectangle image, the medianBlur produces strange effects...

Here the result: http://fff.azurewebsites.net/opencv.png

The code that I use:

```c++
// get the pixels from the WriteableBitmap
byte* pPixels = GetPointerToPixelData(m_bitmap->PixelBuffer);
int height = m_bitmap->PixelHeight;
int width = m_bitmap->PixelWidth;

// create a matrix the size and type of the image
cv::Mat mat(width, height, CV_8UC4);
memcpy(mat.data, pPixels, 4 * height*width);

cv::Mat timg(mat);
cv::medianBlur(mat, timg, 9);
cv::Mat gray0(timg.size(), CV_8U), gray;

// copy processed image back to the WriteableBitmap
memcpy(pPixels, timg.data, 4 * height*width);

// update the WriteableBitmap
m_bitmap->Invalidate();
```

I did'nt find where the problem is... Is it a bug in my code ? or a bug of OpenCV 3 ? from the code of MS Open Tech ?

Thanks for your help !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are inverting the height and the width when creating the cv::Mat.
[Opencv Doc on Mat](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/basic_structures.html#mat)

according to the doc, you should create like that :

```
Mat img(height, width, CV_8UC3);
```

When you use cv::Size however, you give the width first.

```
Mat img(Size(width,height),CV_8UC3);
```

It is a bit confusing, but there is certainly a reason.

Comment: lol, thank you so much ! It works like a charm :D
Thank MS for your sample with that litle error ;)

Comment: @biquette the reason probably is, that there exist two conventions in mathematics: matrix convention indexing: row first. image convention: x axis first. That might be the same reason why there exist two ways to access a matrix element with `.at` one in matrix convention (row first) and one in image convention `Point`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code,change some code.

```
  // get the pixels from the WriteableBitmap
    byte* pPixels = GetPointerToPixelData(m_bitmap->PixelBuffer);
    int height = m_bitmap->PixelHeight;
    int width = m_bitmap->PixelWidth;

    // create a matrix the size and type of the image
    cv::Mat mat(cv::Size(width, height), CV_8UC3);
    memcpy(mat.data, pPixels, sizeof(byte) * height*width);

    cv::Mat timg(mat.size(),CV_8UC3);
    cv::medianBlur(mat, timg, 9);
  //  cv::Mat gray0(timg.size(), CV_8U), gray;

    // copy processed image back to the WriteableBitmap
    memcpy(pPixels, timg.data,sizeof(byte) * height*width);

    // update the WriteableBitmap
    m_bitmap->Invalidate();
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for you reply, but it doesnt work... There is strange effect on the top...